# Angular anchor link inside md-list-item with additional checkbox - prevent default action

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, material-design, angular-material

I am trying to insert `<a>` link inside `<p>` tag that is placed in `<md-list-item>`. Seems simple but problem comes when at the same I would like to **prevent checking checkbox** that is also placed inside this list item when clicking the link.

[image]

Code:

```
  <md-list>
        <md-list-item ng-class="md-2-line">
            <div class="md-list-item-text">
                <p>I agree <a href="www.termsandconditions.com">Terms & Conditions</a></p>
            </div>
            <md-checkbox class="md-secondary"></md-checkbox>
        </md-list-item>
        ... other options ...
    </md-list>
```

I tried:

```
....... HTML.......
<a ng-click="vm.openLink('someurl')">Terms & Conditions</a>

....... JS.......
function openLink(url, $event) {
        $window.open(url, '_blank');
        $event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    }
```

As well as with:

- $event.preventDefault
- $event.stopPropagation
- $event.stopImmediatePropagation
- returning false

**All of them ends in opening the link but at the same time check box is toggled**

How can I prevent checking the checkbox when clicking the link in md-list ?

Comment: `NodeJS highly consuming CPU` - How is NodeJS involved in this?

Comment: Can you not just reverse the checkbox value when the anchor tag is clicked?

Comment: As I mentioned above, you can [do something like this](https://jsfiddle.net/zxd13eL8/)

Comment: @OmriLuzon I removed the information about NodeJS freeze. It was caused by some external actions that were not relevant to the problem. Sorry for introducing unnecessary details that may lead to missunderstanding the problem/question.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps you:

A workaround is: wrap the md-checkbox inside a div element with a ng-repeat attribute:

```
<div ng-repeat="v in [0]">
   <md-checkbox aria-label="" ng-model=""></md-checkbox>
</div>
```

the click event will stop bubbling up.

[Github discussion about this](https://github.com/angular/material/issues/2819)

Comment: Thanks Foo, but that works well only if I would like to prevent checking the checkbox at all but I am looking for a solution to prevent checking only when user clicks link. Otherwise I would like to leave the default behavior.